# RangeError in LIstview.builder with vairable itemcount not working properly

Tags: listview, flutter

I have been trying to build listView from a list which is being updated after each iteration, I dont know the exact problem i've added everything.

Photos:[1. Initial Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THbYh.png),[2. ErrorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKZQF.png),
It jumps out of the listview.builder before the itemcount is finished,2. Error log:

```
flutter: [A]
flutter: [A, I]
flutter: [I, A, R]
flutter: [A, R, I, T]
flutter: [A, I, T, R, E]
flutter: [I, R, T, E, A, L, Q, F, N, F, C, I, M, D, T, F, F, L, H, G]
flutter: [R]
flutter: [R, E]
flutter: [R, E, L]
flutter: [R, L, E, I]
flutter: [E, L, R, I, A]
flutter: [I, L, A, E, R, N]
flutter: [E, I, A, N, L, R, C]

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following RangeError was thrown building:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 7

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:149:60)
#1      _WordGameState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:clone_4pic_1word/wordgame.dart:291:52)
#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:446:15)
#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1260:67)
#4      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:139:29)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (2) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 8
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (3) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 9
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (4) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 10
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (5) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (6) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (7) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (8) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (9) Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 15
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (10) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 16
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (11) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 17
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (12) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: [R, A, I, N, L, E, C, E, E, E, F, U, T, H, L, Q, B, F, B, H]

════════ (13) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..6, inclusive: 19
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

,further it starts working again but then gives error when the next word is bigger than previous i.e itemcount of the next word isbigger than previous one.[3. Works for smaller count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyYEt.png),[4. Gives error again here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsCk3.png),4. Error log:

```
flutter: [F]
flutter: [F, A]
flutter: [A, F, T, V, T, J, C, S, R, M, J, P, L, T, Y, I, P, T, W, D]
flutter: [U]
flutter: [U, N]
flutter: [N, U, I]
flutter: [N, U, I, L]

════════ (14) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 4
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (15) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 5
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (16) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 6
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (17) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 7
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (18) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 8
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (19) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 9
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (20) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 10
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (21) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 11
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (22) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 12
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (23) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 13
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (24) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 14
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (25) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 15
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (26) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 16
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (27) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 17
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ (28) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 18
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: [U, L, N, I, E]

════════ (29) Exception caught by widgets library ══════════════════════════════════════════════════
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..3, inclusive: 19
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: [N, U, I, E, L, V]
flutter: [I, L, N, E, U, V, E]
flutter: [U, E, I, V, E, L, N, R, I, J, V, P, Z, W, O, M, U, R, G, N]
```

Code:

```
  List data;
  double screenWidth, screenHeight;
  int value = 0;
  List<String> l = [];
  int lengthAnswer;
  bool visiblity = false;
  bool visiblityAnswer = true;
  String submittext = "Submit";
  bool onyesbutton = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
  }

  final answercontroller = new TextEditingController();

  Future<String> getData() async {
    var res =
        await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    this.setState(() {
      var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
      data = resBody["results"];
    });

    return "Success!";
  }

  _addItem() {
    setState(() {
      value = value + 1;
      answercontroller.text = "";
      onyesbutton=true;
      visiblity = false;
      visiblityAnswer = true;
    });
  }

  _shuffle() {
    var random = new Random();

    // Go through all elements.
    for (var i = l.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      // Pick a pseudorandom number according to the list length
      var n = random.nextInt(i + 1);
      var temp = l[i];
      l[i] = l[n];
      l[n] = temp;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    screenHeight = size.height;
    screenWidth = size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("4pic1game"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            height: screenHeight,
            width: screenWidth,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: 
                Visibility(
                  visible: visiblityAnswer,
                  maintainSize: false,
                  maintainState: true,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 15,
                    ),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: (data[value]["answer"]).toString().length,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (
                            BuildContext context,
                            int count,
                          ) {
                            lengthAnswer =
                                (data[value]["answer"]).toString().length;
                            l.add(data[value]["answer"]
                                .toString()
                                .toUpperCase()
                                .substring(count, count + 1));
                            // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
                              if (l.length == lengthAnswer) {
                                for (int i = l.length; i < 20; i++) {
                                  _randomString(l);
                                }
                              }
                              print(l);
                            _shuffle();
                            return WordCardAns(
                              count: count,
                              string: data[value]["answer"]
                                  .toString()
                                  .toUpperCase()
                                  .substring(count, count + 1),
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: visiblityAnswer,
                  maintainSize: false,
                  maintainState: true,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                      controller: answercontroller,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.blue,
                        hoverColor: Colors.yellow,
                        focusColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(5)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          letterSpacing: 5),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                        onPressed:()=> onyesbutton ? showAlertDialog(context) : null,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        splashColor: Colors.pink,
                        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        child: Text(
                          "Answer",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      RaisedButton(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        onPressed: () => checkanswer(
                            answercontroller.text, data[value]["answer"]),
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        splashColor: Colors.green,
                        animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        child: Text(
                          submittext,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenWidth / 6,
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: visiblityAnswer,
                  maintainSize: false,
                  maintainState: true,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (
                          BuildContext context,
                          int count,
                        ) {
                          return WordCard(string: l[count]);
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: visiblityAnswer,
                  maintainState: true,
                  maintainSize: false,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (
                          BuildContext context,
                          int count,
                        ) {
                          //     _randomString(l);
                          return WordCard(string: l[count + 10]);
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void checkanswer(String s, String s2) {
    if (s == s2.toUpperCase() || visiblityAnswer == false) {
      l.clear();
      _addItem();
    } else {
      answercontroller.text = "";
    }
  }

  void _randomString(List l) {
    int temp;
    var rand = new Random();
    var list = [
      'a',
      'b',
      'c',
      'd',
      'e',
      'f',
      'g',
      'h',
      'i',
      'j',
      'k',
      'l',
      'm',
      'n',
      'o',
      'p',
      'q',
      'r',
      's',
      't',
      'u',
      'v',
      'w',
      'x',
      'y',
      'z'
    ];
    temp = 1 + rand.nextInt(25);
    l.add((list[temp]).toUpperCase());
  }

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text("No"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
    Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text("Yes"),
      onPressed: () {
        onyesbutton=!onyesbutton;
        onyesalert();
        },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("AlertDialog"),
      content: Text("Are you Sure?"),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
      elevation: 5,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
      ),
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  void onyesalert() {
    {
      setState(() {
        visiblity = true;
        visiblityAnswer = false;
        submittext = "Next";
      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `itemCount: data == null ? 0 : 1,` ?

Comment: Bcoz i just need data of 1 item at a time on the screen